# I need the script for an emp id should start with character "E" using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I need the code using a JavaScript client validation to check emp id should start with character "E" with numeric code(eg:E001). Before submitting the form this validation should be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use [FormAutoValidate](http://phrogz.net/JS/FormAutoValidate/formautovalidate_docs.html) *(disclaimer: my library)*, then you would use:

```
<form class="autovalidate" ...>
  <input type="text" name="empid" class="required" mustmatch="^E\d+$"
   mustmatchmessage="Employee IDs must be of the form 'E001'.">
</form>
```

This is *not* syntactically valid HTML, but works fine in every browser.

*(I do plan on switching to use HTML5 `data-*` attributes for syntactic correctness under HTML5 sometime soon.)*

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="Javascript">

function formCheck()
{
    errstr = "";

    // validates 'E' followed by one or more digits
    if(document.empform.empid.search(/^E\d+$/)==-1)
        errstr += "Invalid EMPid\n";

    if(errstr!="")
    {
        alert(errstr);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

</script>

....

<form name="empform" .... onsubmit="formCheck()" >
...
<input type="text" name="empid">
...
</form>
```